# disable single inbox for multiple MS Exchange email accounts in Mail app on a Mac

Tags: mail.app, exchange

A colleague added an extra MS exchange email account to her Mac Mail app.

Unfortunately, the emails to this address are being saved into the inbox for the other MS exchange email account.

How do we separate the two inboxes please?

Thanks.

Comment: There should be a triangle next to the inbox that should unfold it into 1 inbox per account

Comment: Thanks @KevinGrabher, I think our user was confused, but that definitely helped. Add an answer and I'll accept it if you like.

Comment: @Steve I'm adding it as an answer for now for sake of completeness since it's been a while since he commented, if Kevin shows up I'll let him have the accepted answer and bounty.

Answer (score 1):

You can view each inbox separately. In the left hand column, click the triangle next to the Inbox, then select the inbox you'd like to look at.

[image]